# what happends to the thread if we free its pointer

Tags: c, multithreading

What is the impact of freeing the struct that holds the pthread_t on the thread itself?
I have a struct that represents a thread:

```
typedef struct car{
int cur_place;
pthread_t car_thread;
}car;
```

and i have an array that holds these cars, after some time i want to free the struct from **inside** the thread, i mean:

```
void * car_thread(void * number){
int num = *(int *)number;
    free(maze[num]);
    maze[num] = NULL;
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

is it possible? what will happen to the thread after i free the pthread that holds it? will the it run the next lines?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing happens. Make sure you have a way to detach the thread, though.

Comment: it's just a handle to your thread, nothing happens to the thread, it's the same as doing i=0, x=0, anything=0, you just clear a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeing `car` only releases the memory used to store those values.  The thread will still be other there somewhere possibly.  Think of `pthread_t` as simply holding a number or address used by the system to talk about the thread.  Not the thread itself.

Just don't refer to the memory of `car` anywhere after its free'd.

Comment: Be glad you didn't talk to my cousin.  He used to tell people that they had to warn their friends before they deleted numbers from their cell phone directory or else the phone company would turn the other phone off.

Answer (score 2):

You have just freed the location storing thread's ID, the data structure which stores thread attributes is freed when you do `pthread_exit(NULL)`. Therefore answer to your question: thread stll exists.

Answer (score 0):

The thread will not exit until pthread_exit() is called or, in the case you have signal handling built in, a signal for exiting has been received. The thread is attached to the process but different threads are isolated entities until you tie them up in any kind of thread organization. Apologize for the vague phrasing but this the best way I can describe it.

If you intend to signal the cars to exit when you free the data structure, you need to have signal handling build in to notify each thread to exit. Or, call pthread_exit() in each thread somehow.